# using Ryacas to evaluate expressions

Tags: ryacas

Looking at the documentation here
https://r-cas.github.io/ryacas/reference/y_eval.html

and saw this example:

```
eq <- ysym("2*y+x^2+2*x-3")
y_eval(eq, x=3, y=2)
```

I get:

Error in y_eval(eq, x = 3, y = 2) : could not find function "y_eval"

I tried yacas_eval and other variations (y_evaluate).

What is the command to evaluate this expression please?

I really want to be able to do something like this in the end.

```
a = as_r(yac_str("Simplify(7/8*x)"))
b = as_r(yac_str("y_eval(a^2)"))
```

i.e. square 7/8x to get 49/64x^2